# Spring Data JPA How to use Predicate in Specifiaction

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, predicate

I would like to create Specification to dynamic search.
In database I have fields like radius, width and height - depends on type of shape.

I want to add request paramter like for example areaTo - which will be returing shapes with area smaller or equal to paramter.

I was thinking about adding some Predicate but I can not find any example how to do it.
What I mean, I would like to add something like that:

```
public static Specification<ShapeEntity> areaTo(double areaTo) {
    return (root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> {
        double area;
        switch (root.get("type").toString()) {
            case "CIRCLE":
                area = Math.pow(Double.parseDouble(root.get("radius").toString()), 2) * Math.PI;
                break;
            case "RECTANGLE":
                area = Double.parseDouble(root.get("width").toString()) * Double.parseDouble(root.get("height").toString());
                break;
            case "SQUARE":
                area = Math.pow(Double.parseDouble(root.get("width").toString()), 2);
                break;
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        return criteriaBuilder.lessThanOrEqualTo(????, areaTo);
    };
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution that somewhat answers your question, what you need to create here is an `Expression`.

you could try to modify this code to suit what you need:

```
private Specification<Shape> areaTo(double areaTo, String type) {
    return (root, query, criteriaBuilder) -> {
        Expression<Double> area;
        switch (type) {
            case "CIRCLE":
                Expression<Double> radius = root.get("radius");
                Expression<Double> power = criteriaBuilder.prod(radius, radius);
                area = criteriaBuilder.prod(power, Math.PI);
                break;
            case "RECTANGLE":
                Expression<Double>  width = root.get("width");
                Expression<Double> height = root.get("height");
                area = criteriaBuilder.prod(width, height);
                break;
            case "SQUARE":
                Expression<Double> width_s = root.get("width");
                area = criteriaBuilder.prod(width_s, width_s);
                break;
            default:
                throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        return criteriaBuilder.lessThanOrEqualTo(area, areaTo);
    };
}
```

your `switch (root.get("type").toString())` won't work in the switch statement because there is no value return here, they creating a query. In this situation, you could create a `Predicate` for each type of shape and then add them to `criteriaBuilder` with operator `or`

for further information about my solution you should take a look at this [link](https://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/arithmetic)